# Math method that does not send negative numbers

Tags: javascript, methods, discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a Discord bot using JavaScript, the bot features many commands, but I just came across this flaw, the flaw concerns the `Math.Random()` object, except it sometimes returns negative numbers, does anyone have a solution to this using one of the methods?

**Here's the code::**

```
let db = require(`quick.db`)

module.exports = {
  name: "rob",
  description: "Rob your friends to get money",
  category: "economy",
  usage: "rob [member]",
  timeout: "1 minute",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    let victim = message.mentions.members.first()
    if(!victim) {
      return message.channel.send(`:x: Please specify a member to rob!`)
    }

    let victimW = await db.get(`wallet_${victim.id}`)
    if(victimW === null) {
      message.channel.send(`:x: That user doesn't have money in his wallet, are you sure you want to rob him?`)
    }

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if(random < 30) {
      let victimWallet = await db.get(`wallet_${victim.id}`)
      let userWallet = await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`)
      let amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * victimWallet);
      const messages = [`POG! You robbed **${victim.username}** and got **${amount}** :coin:!`, `oo seems like you robbed **${victim.displayName}** and got **${amount}** :coin:!`]
      const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
      message.channel.send(randomMessage)
      await db.set(`wallet_${victim.id}`, amount - victimWallet)
      await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, userWallet + amount)



    } else if(random > 30) {

      let authorWallet = await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`)
      let wallet1 = await db.get(`wallet_${victim.id}`)
      let amountPaid = Math.floor(Math.random() * authorWallet);
      const message1 = [`Pfft noob, you got caught and paid **${victim.displayName} ${amountPaid}** :coin: lol!`, `lel ure such a noob, you paid **${victim.displayName} ${amountPaid}** :coin:!`, `u suck and you paid **${amountPaid}** :coin: to **${victim.displayName}**, such a noob lol!`]
      const randomMessage1 = message1[Math.floor(Math.random() * message1.length)];
      return message.channel.send(randomMessage1)
      await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, (amountPaid - authorWallet));
      await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, (amountPaid + wallet1));
    }
  }
}
```

It all works except sometimes it just sends a negative number, can anyone tell me a math method that make sure the number isn't a negative?
Thanks.

Comment: `Math.random()` always returns a number between 0 and 1. Can you explain your issue further?

Comment: I doubt that is happening with Math.random(). It is the value you are multiplying it against is negative. So sounds like you need to not rob the victim when it is less than zero. You do not exit out.....

Comment: **The Math. random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1) with approximately uniform distribution over that range — which you can then scale to your desired range.**
so no math.random is not returning a negative number. 
You have a peace of code that retracts `victimWallet` from `amount` that's how you'd get negative number.

Comment: So do not steal if it is less than zero....

Comment: @Kiruna Oh I realize, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kiruna So can you show me a solution?
Thanks

Comment: as @epascarello mentions > `So sounds like you need to *not* rob the victim when it is less than zero `

Comment: `const victimWallet = await db.get(\`wallet_${victim.id}\`);
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
if(victimWallet && victimWallet > 0 && random < 30) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should verify the amount to steal before stealing it

```
if (random < 30) {
    let victimWallet = await db.get(`wallet_${victim.id}`)
    let userWallet = await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`)
    let amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * victimWallet);
    //Check the amount of victim wallet, return if not enough coins to steal
    if (amount > victimwallet) {
        console.log("Not enough coins to steal") return;
    }
    const messages = [`POG! You robbed **${victim.username}** and got **${amount}** :coin:!`, `oo seems like you robbed **${victim.displayName}** and got **${amount}** :coin:!`]
    const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    message.channel.send(randomMessage)
    await db.set(`wallet_${victim.id}`, amount - victimWallet)
    await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, userWallet + amount)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the point is just to make the output to always positive, you can try this "if condition"

```js
var x = -10 //change it with any number
    
if (x < 0){
   x = x * -1
}
    
console.log(x) //it should will always show positive number
```

alternatively you can always use `Match.abs(x)`

```js
var x = -10;

console.log(Math.abs(x));
```

Comment: The Math.random() simply never return a negative value. He should verify if the amount to steal is inferior or equal to the wallet of the victim

Comment: Yah i know that, i'm just try to answer his last question in the bottom, "can anyone tell me a math method that make sure the number isn't a negative". And i'm try my best to find the logic if he just want the output to not to negative. I mean not the output of Math.random(), but the output where he want it to not to be negative number :)

Comment: But yah, your answer @rootmeih looks prety logical, thanks for the new knowledge!